# MySQL: Grouping Spotify tracks by name and artists

Tags: mysql, sql, spotify

I've downloaded track information from Spotify, but many songs have multiple releases that I want to try to consolidate. For instance, there are 6 different track records for Rihanna's 'Love On The Brain' available in the US. In this case, I can simply compare the track name and artist ID, and determine they're all (roughly) the same song. However, when a track has several artists, it becomes (I think) a little more difficult.

I have three tables connected to this issue: Tracks, which contains a row for each track with some fun data I want to analyze, Artists, which contains a row for each artist, and Track_artists, which contains a row for each track-artist pair, with an auto-incremented track_artist_id. So for the song Work, I'd have 1 or more Track rows (depending on the number of releases), 1 Artist row for Rihanna and 1 for Drake, and then for each row in Tracks, 2 rows in Track_artists:
So the following query gives the following results:

```
select ta.track_id, ta.artist_id, a.name 
from track_artists ta inner join artists a on ta.artist_id=a.artist_id
inner join tracks t on t.track_id=ta.track_id 
where t.name='Work';

+------------------------+------------------------+-------------+
| track_id               | artist_id              | name        |
+------------------------+------------------------+-------------+
| 0ghpAAdn5OmxvI7ul5DR2B | 5pKCCKE2ajJHZ9KAiaK11H | Rihanna     |
| 0ghpAAdn5OmxvI7ul5DR2B | 3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4 | Drake       |
| 32lmL4vQAAotg6MrJnhlQZ | 5pKCCKE2ajJHZ9KAiaK11H | Rihanna     |
| 32lmL4vQAAotg6MrJnhlQZ | 3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4 | Drake       |
| 4aRD0bzvsBD0MAB4LcsRSM | 5pKCCKE2ajJHZ9KAiaK11H | Rihanna     |
| 4aRD0bzvsBD0MAB4LcsRSM | 3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4 | Drake       |
| 4m6D70k5xMmCDCB19u7Bi0 | 5pKCCKE2ajJHZ9KAiaK11H | Rihanna     |
| 4m6D70k5xMmCDCB19u7Bi0 | 3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4 | Drake       |
+------------------------+------------------------+-------------+
```

It's obvious to me that these are all the same song, but what's the best way to group them? My solution would be:

```
select t.track_id,t.name,a1.artist_id first_artist,a2.artist_id second_artist
from track_artists a1 inner join tracks t on t.track_id=a1.track_id 
inner join track_artists a2 on t.track_id=a2.track_id 
where t.name='Work' and 
a1.artist_id = (select artist_id from track_artists where track_id = t.track_id limit 1) and 
a2.artist_id = (select artist_id from track_artists where track_id = t.track_id limit 1,1);
+------------------------+------+------------------------+------------------------+
| track_id               | name | first_artist           | second_artist          |
+------------------------+------+------------------------+------------------------+
| 0ghpAAdn5OmxvI7ul5DR2B | Work | 5pKCCKE2ajJHZ9KAiaK11H | 3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4 |
| 32lmL4vQAAotg6MrJnhlQZ | Work | 5pKCCKE2ajJHZ9KAiaK11H | 3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4 |
| 4aRD0bzvsBD0MAB4LcsRSM | Work | 5pKCCKE2ajJHZ9KAiaK11H | 3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4 |
| 4m6D70k5xMmCDCB19u7Bi0 | Work | 5pKCCKE2ajJHZ9KAiaK11H | 3TVXtAsR1Inumwj472S9r4 |
+------------------------+------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

And then just add a group by t.name,first_artist,second_artist.

Is this really the best way to do this? Especially considering that some of the songs have more than 10 artists collaborating? Have I built my database poorly?

Comment: I suspect there are other tables that have the information you are looking for.  The data that you have provided does not distinguish between multiple tracks for artists on one song, and multiple songs with the same artists.

Comment: I'm making the assumption that an artist isn't going to make two songs called the exact same thing, but Spotify doesn't actually do any automatic linking between two releases of the same song.